# Resizing binary mask stored in numpy array

Tags: python, image-segmentation, scikit-image, semantic-segmentation

I have got numpy arrays consisting of only 0s and 1s. They are supposed to be the target for an Image Segmentation Model, so I am trying to resize them all so they have the same dimensions. The problem is that when resizing with the code below, the image is not being kept as a binary. Instead, I get a lot of float values between 0 and 1, which seem to be affecting my model's performance.

```
import skimage.transform as st

new_label_data = st.resize(label_data, (1024, 1024), order=0, anti_aliasing=False)
```

So that begs the question: how can I resize the binary arrays and make sure the output also has only 0s and 1s?

Comment: is label_data of dtype bool? probably not because then transform.resize would have reacted to that. -- so just binarize the result? some non-binary values near the edges shouldn't affect the model. *look* at your data (show us your inputs and outputs)

Comment: No, label_data is a numpy array of type int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preserve_range=True` as well:

```py
new_label_data = st.resize(label_data, (1024, 1024), order=0, preserve_range=True, anti_aliasing=False)
```

See [`st.resize`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize) for more details.